# Is it possible this is sunlight?

Tags: light, outdoor, indoor, sunlight, vintage

Is this sunlight on his right shoulder? It doesn't seem like the angle is correct for this light to be sunlight.[image]

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it's coming in through the top of the partially opened door to the left.

Comment: If that is the case, why aren't there any 'rays' coming through the door opening?

Comment: @Patrick If there aren't a lot of particulates in the air, then there's nothing to reflect the light to create rays. Note also that the sunlight crack isn't the only light source: there's a flash shining from above the upper left shoulder of the photographer. Look at the subject's shadow on the door behind him — the shadow is slightly to the right of and below the subject's ear. Additional light in the scene from the flash will swamp out softer features such as sun rays coming from the cracked open door.